# How to extract first 3 characters from two fields (in SOQL)

Tags: apex, soql

I am trying to modify following SOQL statement so that query only retrieves if first 3 characters of FirstName AND first 3 characters of LastName match.

This is part of my original SOQL statement.

```
SELECT id__c, 
       LName__c, 
       FName__c,
       FROM Patient__c
       where
       LName__c =:lname and FName__c =:fname
```

I know I should use an expression like LEFT(LName__c, 3), but I am not sure how I could apply.

Bottom is part of Apex code where this SOQL runs:

```
public PageReference searchPatients(){

    RowList = new List<TableRow2>();
    TableRow2 tr;

    if (fname != null) fname = fname.left(3);
    if (lname != null) lname = lname.left(3);

    for(Patient__c con : [SELECT sfprn__c, 
                                mrn__c,
                                LName__c, 
                                FName__c,
                                (select SurveySelection__c.SurveySelection__c from SurveySelections__r) 
                                FROM Patient__c
                                where ( mrn__c =:mrn ) 
                      or ( LName__c LIKE :lname + '%' and FName__c LIKE :fname + '%' ) LIMIT 1                      
                         ]){                                    
        tr = new TableRow2();
        tr.sfprn = con.sfprn__c;
        tr.mrn = con.mrn__c;
        tr.lname = con.LName__c;
        tr.fname = con.FName__c;
        tr.SurveySelection = con.SurveySelections__r.isEmpty() ? null : con.SurveySelections__r[0].SurveySelection__c;

        RowList.add(tr); 
     }
     return null;   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to check if a field starts with a specific value, use `LIKE` with a terminating wildcard:

```
WHERE LName__c LIKE 'abc%'
```

Depending where you get these `fname and`lname` values from, you may need to add this wildcard yourself:

```
WHERE FName__c LIKE :fname + '%'
AND LName__c LIKE :lname + '%'
```

If you want to make sure you check exactly three characters, you can manipulate the bind variables as necessary, but have to ask yourself some questions. If the length is less than three, do you throw an exception? Anyway, if it's longer, you can, as mentioned above, trim it down to the desired length:

```
if (fname != null) fname = fname.left(3);
if (lname != null) lname = lname.left(3);
```

---

Here is a more complete syntax:

```
public List<Patient__c> matchFirstThreeCharacters(String firstName, String lastName)
{
    if (firstName != null) firstName = firstName.left(3);
    if (lastName != null) lastName = lastName.left(3);
    // what do you do if they are null? error case?

    return [
        SELECT FName__c, LName__c FROM Patient__c
        WHERE FName__c LIKE :firstName + '%'
        AND LName__c LIKE :lastName + '%'
    ];
}
```

Comment: If the requirement is about first three characters, how do I express it?

Comment: @KingJava You just make sure it starts with the bind value. If you want to, you can verify the length of the bind value and truncate it if necessary.

Comment: I added other code to have a better picture. My question now is: On the "If" statement above, do you express inside SOQL statement? I guess I am not understanding how "bind value/variable" works.

Comment: @KingJava No, you would use the `if` blocks to truncate the name values if they are longer than you want, *before* binding them into your query.

Comment: @KingJava Are you still stuck on this one then?

Comment: Yes. Adrian. I am still getting an error (unexpected token: '3') on the expression to show first three character on SOQL statement. What should be the expression?

Comment: You can't call functions on a field. Look at the `WHERE` clause in my first example. That's the syntax you need to use. I added a more complete example. @KingJava

Comment: The error is gone, but now the issue is related to logic of how List (RowList / tr ) works. When I press a "search" button, the data does not come out as it should be. How do I go about incorporating "if (firstName != null).." logic in this function?